# Why a character can be displayed, but a string can't with `int 0x10` in assembly language in this situation?

Tags: assembly, virtualbox, nasm, x86-16, osdev

I'm new to operating system development. Today, I'm trying to write a bootloader with NASM, and I wrote this code:

```
org 0x7c00
mov ax, cs
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
call dispStr
jmp $

dispStr:
    mov ax, 0x0003
    int 0x10
    mov ax, BootMessage
    mov bp, ax
    mov cx, 16
    mov ax, 0x1301
    mov bx, 0x001f
    mov dl, 0x0000
    int 0x10
    ret

BootMessage db "Hello, OS world!"

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0

dw 0xaa55
```

It is expected to display a white string "**Hello, OS world!**" on blue background, and the cursor will move after the end of the string. And it worked, but not completely. In my virtualbox, it showed up like this:

[image]

It has just a blue background without any white pixels.

But it worked completely with this code:

```
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, 'X'
int 0x10

jmp $

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0

dw 0xaa55
```

So I think my development environment is correct. I want to find why it happened.

I'm using nasm+wsl+VSCode+virtualbox, and this is my `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "nasm-binary",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "nasm",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-f",
                "bin",
                "-o",
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.bin",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "dd-BIOS",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "wsl",
            "args": [
                "dd",
                "if=/mnt/d/****/LearnOS/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.bin",
                "of=/mnt/d/****/VBOX/0.vhd",
                "bs=512",
                "count=1",
                "conv=notrunc"
            ],
            "dependsOn": "nasm-binary",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Here `0.vhd` is a virtual disk created with `diskpart.exe`, its command is

`create vdisk file=D:\****\VBOX\0.vhd maximum=10 type=fixed` .

While running `dd-BIOS` task, both `nasm-binary` and `dd-BIOS` run.

And this is my virtual machine:

[image]

You can reproduce the wrong.

Comment: First image is the same as second image for some reason. Please edit to fix that.

Comment: Another comment: `mov ax, cs` should be the first instruction before using `ax` to write to `ds` and `es`. However, `cs` can be either 0 or 7C0h and you shouldn't depend on this. So instead the sequence should be: `org 7C00h` \ `xor ax, ax  ; zero ax` \ `mov ds, ax` \ `mov es, ax`

Comment: Probably the color is wrong, experiment with the value in BL. (0x17 instead of 1f?)

Comment: Using the current code (with `mov ax, cs` or `xor ax, ax` as first instruction) works for me in qemu.

Comment: @ecm Thank you. With `xor ax, ax` for init, it works now, instead of `mov ax, cs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For real mode the CPU calculates a physical address by doing `physical_address = (segment * 16 + offset) & A20_gate_mask` (where `A20_gate_mask` is either 0xFFFFFFFF if A20 gate is enabled or 0xFFEFFFFF if A20 is disabled).

For BIOS, the only strict requirement is that your boot loader will begin at physical address 0x00007C00. This means that (when jumping to your boot loader) BIOS can set `CS:IP` to anything that satisfies `(segment * 16 + offset) & A20_gate_mask == 0x00007C00`. Often (depending on which computer) this will be either 0x0000:0x7C00 or 0x07C0:0x0000; but it could be 0x0100:0x6C00 or 0x0123:69D0, or (if A20 is disabled) 0xFFFF:0x7C10, or anything else.

By telling the assembler `org 0x7C00` you're telling it that offsets from the start of your program (e.g. the `BootMessage` label) are offsets from 0x7C00. If CS happens to be 0x0000 and is copied into ES, then `ES:BootMessage` will be a correct `segment:offset` for the physical address of the string. If CS happens to be any other value then `ES:BootMessage` will be an incorrect `segment:offset` for the physical address of the string and you'll print garbage.

The best/easiest solution (especially if you switch to protected mode or long mode later) is to avoid all the unnecessary confusion by setting all segment registers to zero where possible (and enabling A20 later); so that the address calculation effectively becomes `physical_address = offset`. This can be done with a far jump (e.g. `jmp 0x0000:start` then `start:`) before copying CS into other segment registers, but if you know CS will be zero it's faster to load an explicit zero into other segment registers.

*Note: in most cases you could cheat and leave CS alone (`call` and most jumps will work regardless because they are relative to IP), but it's easier (for debugging, etc) to do all segment registers and not have to worry about accidentally using less common cases where calls/jumps are not relative.*

The other thing you should do (eventually) is set up a safe stack at a known location so that you can use other memory (e.g. to load a kernel) without worrying about trashing your own stack. There's no rule about what BIOS left in SS:SP (or where the stack you start using is).

The full "safe startup" sequence might be:

```
    org 0x7C00

    jmp 0x0000:start
start:
    xor ax,ax              ;Set AX to zero
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax

    cli                    ;Only needed for 8086
    mov ss,ax
    mov sp,0x7C00          ;SS:SP = 0x0000:0x7C00 = about 30 KiB of stack space below boot loader's code
    sti

    cld                    ;Clear direction flag (used by instructions like "rep movsb" and "lodsb").
```

Comment: Missing the comment that `ss` should be set in the instruction immediately before the one setting `sp`. Example is right but it is important to note.